What does "pbreaks", etc in the Modelica.Media.R134a.R134Data, mean?
I use the Openmodelica(v1.21.0) with MSL 4.0.
Now I try to understand Modelica.Media.R134a to make a new refrigerant media.
I have a question I would like to ask you about Modelica.Media.R134a.R134aData.
In this package, "pbreaks", "Tbreaks", ... are described as constants.
Q1. What do these constants mean ?
Q2. How do numbers in these constants mean ?
I would be happy to answer the above questions.
I would like to make new refrigerant media.
This is because I do not know how to make new refrigenrant media by using external media.
